# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I get a variable which type is : <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>; I want to get the column name of the Series which is "text" but using .columns or .values.tolist() produce errors.

```
0      'les plantes ont été jusqu au milieu du xxe si...
1      'au cours du moyen âge apparaissent des usages...
2      'john ray naturaliste anglais propose d établi...
3      'un certain nombre d espèces anciennement cons...
4      'les premières classifications semi phylogénét...
                             ...
501    'à partir du xvie siècle les deux termes sont ...
502    'le savant grec considère également possible d...
503    'il en envisage d ailleurs plusieurs selon lui...
504    'la division remonte aux environs du temps d a...
505    'vivants étaient traditionnellement répartis l...
Name: text, Length: 506, dtype: object
```

Want to print something like below when reading the series :

```
for elt in list_of_col_preprocessed[2:5]:
        #print(type(elt))
        print("name of series is :" , elt.columns.tolist())
        emb, s = get_flaubert_layer(elt, path)
        print(emb)
```

but using columns.tolist() get me a error

```
__getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns
__getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns
__getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns
```

Comment: You need `name` not columns: `pd.Series([1,2,3], name='text').name`

Comment: [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)